# React SSR - Rendering a component following an async action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server-side-rendering

React's component lifecycle goes hand in hand with the DOM, so when I'm trying to render on the server side following an async action I'm encountering issues.

I have a component (let's call it the containing component) which is responsible for dynamically importing another component (let's call it the inner component) according to data passed in its props.

Once the import promise is resolved, I'd like to render the inner component inside of the containing component.

The problem is, I have no way of accessing the containing component's lifecycle.

render() is only triggered once upon the construction of the containing component.

Updating the component via forceUpdate() and setState() are not possible for the same reason componentDidMount() will never be called.

How do I render a component following an async action on the server side when using server rendering?

My code so far:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class ComponentLoader extends React.Component<{ component: string }, { component: any }> {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            component: null
        }; //no-op
    }

    componentDidMount(): void {
        //never called
    }

    componentWillMount(): void {
        import('./' + this.props.component).then(module => {
            this.forceUpdate(); //no-op
            this.setState({ component: React.createElement(module.default) }); //no-op
        });
    }

    render() {
        //called only once during construction
        return this.state.component || null; //this.state won't be available, nor will it matter if I access component any other way since render() won't be called again once that component is resolved anyway.
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post relevant codes of what you have tried so far in your question.

Comment: Here you go, added.

Comment: You likely need to refactor the code to be synchronous for the sake of SSR. Use `require`.

Comment: require does the trick for loading sync. How will I solve though other async cases like s2s requests? I won't be able to put await in the constructor for instance. Are there solutions for stuff like that?

Making everything sync aside, is it really not possible to do things async when working with SSR?

Making everything sync might be an issue when trying to scale, i.e. see the warning here, let me know what you think:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/sync-request

Comment: Take a look at `loadable-components`, this is the way to lazy-load React components on the server that is recommended in the official React documentation: https://github.com/smooth-code/loadable-components/blob/master/packages/server/README.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using loadable components, a different implementation than what you see in the comments though.

https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable

https://github.com/konradmi/react-loadable-ssr-code-splitting

On the server side it makes sure to only render the react components once all the dependencies are loaded async. That way the render is sync since that's the only thing that's supported at the moment (though there's a feature request for supporting async react ssr), but the loading is done async, so it doesn't block any other operations.